# Error in RDS: ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '-e' (-2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am facing the error ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '-e' (-2) while trying to create a database in RDS. The DB instance and has the correct security group.

This is the query I ma executing: mysql -uusername -ppassword -h RDS Endpoint -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tablename;CREATE DATABASE tablename;grant REPLICATION CLIENT on *.* to username;grant REPLICATION SLAVE on *.* to username;"

Request you to help with the error.

Thank you.

Checked if the RDS instance has the same desired security group
Tried rebooting the instance

Answer (score 0):

Would be good if could show your actual code, but almost certainly the issue is that your code is broken and not actually supplying the "RDS Endpoint."

You wrote:

> mysql -uusername -ppassword -h RDS Endpoint -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tablename;CREATE DATABASE tablename;grant REPLICATION CLIENT on . to username;grant REPLICATION SLAVE on . to username;"

Well, if I just ignore the "RDS Endpoint" part, I'd get a mysql command like `mysql -username -ppassword -h -e "DROP....."`.  And, this matches the error you are getting "Unknown MySQL server host '-e'".  Because, mysql sees the `-e` after the `-h` and thinks it is the hostname it is supposed to use.